# Angular2: how to provide data to a subscribe() within ngOnInit()?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm working through the Angular2 testing guide and wish to write a test for the ngOnInit() function.

The one from the Routing part of the programming guide has the following format.  The data comes through a resolver.  When fixture.detectChanges() is called my ngOnInit() is called.

```
let org: Org = null;
let savedOrg: Org = null;

...

ngOnInit(): void {
  let that = this;

  this.route.data
    .subscribe((data: { org: Org }) => {
      that.org = data.org;
      that.savedOrg = new Org(that.org);
  });
}
```

In my previous question I concentrated on getting data through the resolver.  User "peeskillet" graciously gave me:

```
let routeStub: any = { data: org1 };
```

However, this (routeStub.data) is what is being seen in ngOnInit() and my code fails by not calling subscribe(), which isn't in my stub.

(Rather than coloring that question with a large update I decided to create this new question.)

Actually, I don't want to replace the ngOnInit() version of this.route.data with a mock.  Rather, I need to pass data into the existing this.route.data.subscribe().

How do I do that?

Thanks,

Jerome.

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION ON 03/11**

What is working for me is only slightly different than what peeskillet recommended.  One, my it() function isn't using the async() function within it.  Two, my routeStub observable needs a named attribute of "org", as in Observable.of({ 'org': org1 }).

Here is my working code all in one place:

```
let org1: Org = new Org({ ... details that fill it ... });
let routeStub: any = { data: Observable.of( { org: org1 } ) } ;

...

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ FormsModule, RouterTestingModule ],
    providers : [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: routeStub }          
    ],
    declarations: [ OrgDetailComponent ],
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OrgDetailComponent);

  ...

});

it('should display original title', () => { 
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h2'));
    el = de.nativeElement;

    expect(comp.org).toEqual(org1);
    expect(el.textContent).toContain("Edit");
  });    
});
```

Then in the component:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
  let that = this;

  this.route.data
    .subscribe((data: { org: Org }) => {
      that.org = data.org;
    });
}
```

Comment: Please look the the test in my answer from your last post.There is a typo. The `route` should be `routeStub`. That should answer your question

Comment: Using a mock is the only way unless you want to setup the whole routung infrastructure, which is not a good idea for unit tests

Comment: If you want to be able to pass multiple values in a test, use a `Suhject` instead of Observable

Comment: Per the "other thread", I added your changes to my program.  I get a two-pronged failure. When I do it(title, async(() => {})) the test isn't run at all (tested through adding console.log() comments).  If I do if(title, {}) then the routeStub.data is OK (has the Observable within it) before detectChanges() is run. But within ngOnInit() the this.route.data is still null. Of course, none of this is documented outside of stackoverflow...

Comment: See the UPDATE section above for my solution.  I won't need any more help on this issue.